cant see all the traces using io.micrometer and io.zipkin.reporter2 @Observed
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* management.endpoint.health.show-details=always management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0

those are set firstly,
now problem is can see traces from one class to another but problem is one of my class use other methods i also want to see their duration too. I put @Observed to my method but cant see them from zipkin interface structre is like this
public class A{
...
@Observed(name = "methodA") //can see this
public void methodA(){
this.b.methodb();
}
...
}

public class B{
...
@Observed(name = "methodB") //can see this
public void methodB(){
methodbc();
}

@Observed(name = "methodbc") //cant see this
public void methodbc(){
...
}
...
}

i also dont have any config classes
tried to see all traces and durations but only two appeared when i checked my zipkin interface
